# VSCode recognises conda environment but not pip packages in Unix

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have a conda environment `conda_env`, which I activate in a Jupyter notebook on Visual Studio Code. The environment contains packages installed using both `conda install` and `pip install`.

The notebook resides in a Unix shell on a remote server. I am able to import packages installed with conda and residing inside the environment path (`miniconda/envs/conda_env/...`). However, when I try to import packages that were installed with pip, the import fails.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-extensions'
```

I can import the packages if I start a Python environment on the command line inside the conda environment. Below shows the path the package is found in.

```
import django_extensions
print(django_extensions.__file__)
# ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_extensions/__init__.py
```

I eventually found a workaround solution by putting this line into the notebook.

```
sys.path.append("~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/")
```

My question is, is there a way to do this across the entire VSC, without me having to manually put that line in inside every notebook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that

`sys.path.append("~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/")`

"*solves*" the issue indicates that the packages were installed with `pip install --user` which is not installing into the environment and generally is [not recommended for Conda users](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env). If you wish to install with Pip in an environment, do not use the `--user` flag.

Having packages installed in user site leads to confusion among users and I recommend users either avoid them altogether (delete any `~/.local/lib/python*`) or install the package `conda-forge::conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation`.